# Javascript function won't pass parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have the following code:

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
  var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/> <a onclick='moreInfo(name)'>Learn More</a>";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}

function moreInfo(name){

    $('#dcFinder').hide();
    $('#moreInfo').show();
    $('#name').html(name);

}
```

Which refers to the google map store locator I'm working on. I'm trying to make a link to the moreInfo function, passing through the name used in the first function.

When the link is clicked, the appropriate divs are shown and hidden, but the name is not showing.

Comment: Use `"<br/> <a onclick='moreInfo(\"" + name + "\")'>Learn More</a>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass through the variable in your html so try this:

```
 var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/> <a onclick=\"moreInfo('" + name + "')\">Learn More</a>";
```

Comment: thanks this seems to be working, how could I add a second parameter to the onclick?

Comment: @CarlaDessi simple: `\"moreInfo('" + name + "', '" + address + "')\"`

Comment: @CarlaDess if the second parameter is a js variable then you would do it as user3280126 has shown above, if it is just a string you are going to pass through then you can do it like this:   `\"moreInfo('" + name + "', 'string to pass')\"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate the string properly and escape quotation marks for the function variable:

```
var html = '<b>' + name + '</b> <br/>' + address + '<br/> <a onclick="moreInfo(\'' + name + '\')">Learn More</a>';
```

Comment: I've tried this but then the link stops working completely, as in none of the divs are hidden/shown

Comment: @CarlaDessi That is weird, are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: This won't work because you are passing through the onclick as a string so the name will be converted to a string - you need quotes around the variable

Comment: @Pete Ah, you are correct. CarlaDessi take a look at Petes answer

Comment: Fixed with quotation marks the other way around ;). Both answers will work now.